# How can you make the timestamps column in Rails accept null values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How can you make the timestamps column in active record based tables not require a value?

I.e. Now when you run the migration:

```
class CreateInstructors < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :instructor do |t|
      t.name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The `created_at` and `updated_at` do not accept null values.  How can you still keep timestamps but allow null values?

Answer (score 1):

Not in favor of doing timestamp as null, it doesn't makes sense.  But if you want to you can have ur migration accept nil values

```
t.column  :created_at , :timestamp, :null => true
t.column  :updated_at , :timestamp, :null => true
```

Then you can create a after callback or with whatever condition you want to make it null

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want a null value for a created_at or updated_at timestamp?

I would suggest creating another field to handle whatever case you are working on, perhaps a boolean or additional timestamp field, rather than repurposing these reserved fields.

However I don't know your use case...

Comment: In case someone goes into the db and does manual data entry - theyd be forced to insert values into those columns

Comment: that is true.  I would try to keep them in the rails app to solve this, or if it is just me editing data, I'd write myself an admin scaffold (or use the activeadmin gem).  Has been easier for me than direct entry in the past.